# Connecting to remote machine from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files from one domain to a remote machine in another domain. I want to use constant credentials. No matter what I tried, it doesn't work. I can ping to the remote machine only via IP and not by hostname.

```
    $labname='L1681'
    $remoteComputer = "10.32.22.157"
    $username = "$labname\Administrator"
    $password =  ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Credential $creds
    $Source = "\\...\folder"
    $Destination = "\\$remoteComputer\c$\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination -Force
    Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Force -ToSession $session
```

I tried to replace the `$labname` with `$remoteComputer`. Each time I get a different error:

```
    Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 10.32.22.157 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: 
    the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more 
    information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Credential $creds
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (10.32.22.157:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

I hope someone can help me with that, is there a way to know when the copy if finished, once it works? Also, how can I run a .bat file in a remote machine?

Comment: Did you check the advice in the official [Remote Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2) documentation?

Comment: Yes, The remote IP was added to the TrustedHosts still get this error:
Copy-Item : The path '\\10.32.22.157\c$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\' is not valid. Only absolute paths are supported on remote copy operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Force -To ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\10.32.22.157\...trator\Desktop\:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePathIsNotAbsolute,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: You mentioned issues pinging the hostname.  If you are in Windows, you might do some test with the PING command in the command prompt.  Giving it hostname.domain.com should return pings, and giving it -a IPAddress should return the hostname.domain.com.  This will give you a baseline of what to expect your program should be able to do.  If PING fails, your program will likely fail as well, but if it succeeds where your program is failing, you may have a coding issue.  I haven't investigated this, but there maybe more than one way to ping from PowerShell, so check for alternatives.

Comment: The ping is not the issue. The ping is working for an IP as expected
The company not letting the option to ping to hostname
The machine is up and running

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script which establishes a remote connection to a VM and copy a text file from the Local directory to that Remote VM.

```
#Provide the Remote VM Username and Password
$myPwd="Your VM Password" 
$username="VM Username" 
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $myPwd -AsPlainText -Force 
$credentials= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

#Create a remote session to that VM
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName FQDN/IP -Credential $credentials

#Check the content to the Local File that will be copied to Remote
Get-Content -Path "C:\LocalFolder\File.txt" 

#Create a folder named *RemoteFolder* then copy the local file to that Folder
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {cd C:\; mkdir RemoteFolder}
Copy-Item –Path "C:\LocalFolder\File.txt" –Destination "C:\RemoteFolder\" –ToSession $Session

#Check the content of the copied file
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Content -Path "C:\RemoteFolder\File.txt" } -Session $Session
```

The screenshot of the output after running this script:

[image]

Comment: Same error....
I want to copy a folder with all her contents from a share location into a remote VM
The example is for one file and maybe working but not in my case

Comment: I have a confusion, Will you please clear me one thing that Can you create a remote session to any VM? Please confirm that you can establish a remote connection to that or another VM and create a folder to that VM via Powershell. I think you have a remote connection issue.

Comment: Yes the folder is created
I want to copy a folder with all the files to the desktop of the remote machine

Comment: I changed the destination to 
$Destination = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
Now its start to copy only the root with an error message
Copy-Item : The data area passed to a system call is too small
What does it mean?

Comment: As per your comment, I understood that you want to copy all files to a folder into the Remote VM folder, Right? to do this you need to run this command: ```Copy-Item -Path "C:\LocalFolder\*" -Destination "C:\RemoteFolder" -PassThru –ToSession $Session ```
Here ```C:\LocalFolder\*``` means all of the files under LocalFolder will be copied to RemoteFolder.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and now it copy all the content (only folders without files) to the desktop, I want to copy the source folder with all the content (Includes sub folders and file) to the desktop  (That mean that in the desktop will be only 1 folder )
-Recurse + your answer leads to the same error (The data area passed to a system call is too small )

Comment: I must say that before the using the session (Writing manually the user and password) 
It worked great as expected. All the content was copied to the remote machine with the same folder name

Comment: ```Copy-Item -Path "C:\LocalFolder\*" -Destination "C:\RemoteFolder" -PassThru –ToSession $Session``` the  ```C:\LocalFolder\*``` ```*``` should copy all of the files of this folder. I think there is some misunderstanding between you and me to express this.  This command will copy all of the files and subfolders (Without the content of the subfolder). You can separately copy the subfolder into the remote folder by running the same command with specifying the subfolder. Thanks

Comment: It not make any sense...I want to copy all the content in one time source = folder1 (With sub folders and files inside ) to target = folder1 (Without creating it before). Just copy as it. 
The * copy all the subfolder to the desktop (Instead to one folder) without files

Comment: Same scenario is working when copying from local computer to remote machine 
Only when copying from the network